# Docker Debian install fails

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile that works, but if I add any new dependencies to the `apt-get install` command, it fails. For example, this works:

```
FROM debian:stable

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y \
    python \
    ...
    apache2
```

But if I try this, it fails:

```
FROM debian:stable

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y \
    python \
    ...
    apache2
    python-mysqldb
```

I can replace `python-mysqldb` with anything else, `git-core`, for example, and it will still fail with the same error message:

```
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 149.20.20.6 80]

E: Aborting install.
```

Any thoughts on why adding a new dependency causes the failure and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that you need to join the update & install command into the same RUN block.

eg:

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y \
    python \
    ...
    apache2 \
    python-mysqldb
```

According to [this post](http://lenguyenthedat.com/docker-cache/) describing the issue

> By default, Docker cache your commands to reduce time spent building
>   images. Unless there was any change before such commands (or at the
>   same line).

Meanwhile, I notice that the [AWS examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html) separate them, as you have them.  So I dunno if it works different there.  Maybe they disable the cache by default.